# ionic cordova-plugin-camerapreview "no preview"

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

i always get following error when i'm trying to start the ionic camera-preview:

*ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): No preview*

I updated all dependencies, added the provider etc. 
but i don't get it running, hope anyone can help me =)

[image]

[image]

The CameraPreviewOptions are copied from the example in the docs.

```
this.cameraPreview.startCamera(this.cameraPreviewOpts).then(
    (res) => {
      console.log(res)
    },
    (err) => {
      console.log(err)
    });
```

Comment: Can you please post the code that shows how you use the plugin?

Comment: @AndreasGassmann i added the code-snippet

Comment: I have the same error... Wish I could help, but at least you know you're not alone. If I figure it out I'll let you know.

Comment: @Lenny finally i found the problem, it occurs when i start the preview in an click event... if i start it in the constructor the everything works fine ^.^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue like you,

The following instructions did the trick for me:

**start**  and then **show** the camera-preview in the `ionViewCanEnter()` lifecycle function.

You have also to be carefull of hiding the camera-preview in the `ionViewWillLeave()` lifecycle function. And also showing it again in the `ionViewWillEnter()` lifecycle function. To be clean.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Your suggestion didnt work for me. Is it because of any permission issue perhaps?